# Кросс-компиляция приложения на C++ с Qt с Linux под Windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt, кросс-компиляция

Здравствуйте! Я начинающий программист и недавно использую Qt. Не могу разобраться с компиляцией приложения на C++ с использованием Qt. Написал простейшую программу под Linux Mint:

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QPoint>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    return app.exec();
}
```

хочу получить .exe. Для этого пытаюсь следовать инструкции отсюда:

https://askubuntu.com/a/656329

Как я понял, там пропущен один шаг. Я делаю так:

```
PATH=<mxe root>:$PATH
export PATH
<mxe root>/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-qmake-qt5 -project
```

Здесь у меня возникает ошибка

```
Project ERROR: Cannot run compiler 'i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++'. Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?
```

Но я её игнорирую и продолжаю:

```
<mxe root>/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-qmake-qt5
make
```

При этом, сразу запустить qmake без -project нельзя, он мне справку выдаёт. А вот после make у меня возникает ошибка:

```
make[1]: i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++: Command not found
```

С ней я разобрался. Надо в Makefile.Release заменить строчки

```
CXX         = i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++
LINKER      = i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++
```

на

```
CXX         = <mxe root>/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++
LINKER      = <mxe root>/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++
```

Но теперь появляется ошибка, которую я уже побороть не могу:

```
fatal error: QWidget: No such file or directory
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что мне делать. И, если возможно, объясните,  почему ещё в том ответе опущена строчка

```
<mxe root>/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-qmake-qt5 -project
```

а мне приходится делать такие странные манипуляции.
Подозреваю, что могут быть какие-то совершенно идиотские ошибки у меня.
И есть ещё проблема, что я не понимаю, какие версии Qt на каком шаге используются. Так сложилось, что я себе поставил как четвёртый, так и пятый Qt. Но, как я понимаю, в вопросе речь идёт о пятом Qt.

Comment: Ответ я сам написал, но он мне не нравится. Буду очень благодарен, если кто-нибудь по-человечески распишет всё.

Answer (score 2):

Делать надо так:

0) Как сказано в ответе https://askubuntu.com/a/656329, надо:

```
git clone https://github.com/mxe/mxe.git
cd mxe && make qtbase
```

1) Добавить в исходник строчку

```
#include <QtWidgets>
```

2) Потом

```
PATH=<mxe root>:$PATH
export PATH
<mxe root>/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-qmake-qt5 -project
<mxe root>/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-qmake-qt5
```

игнорируя возникающую после /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-qmake-qt5 -project ошибку

3) Потом дописать в файл test.pro строку

```
QT += widgets
```

после строки INCLUDEPATH += .

4) Выполнить

```
make
```

Он завершится с ошибкой, но это не конец.

5) Заменить в Makefile.Release

```
CXX = i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++
LINKER  = i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++
```

на

```
CXX = <mxe root>/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++
LINKER  = <mxe root>/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++
```

6) Снова выполнить

```
make
```

И в папке release образуется test.exe

---

Если в мой C++ файл добавить строки

```
QWidget w;
w.show();
```

то после аналогичных манипуляций окошко появляется, проверил под виртуалкой с 64-битной восьмой Windows.

Comment: Как правильный ответ мне это не хочется пока помечать, потому что шаманство какое-то, на мой взгляд.